# If there is a user session in aiogram?

Tags: aiogram

I am making a telgram bot on python with module aiogram
I wanna store some custom data on user side\

If there is a user session in aiogram?

Answer (score 1):

You could store data in [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/fsm.html), or you can save anything in database (SQLite, Postgres, Redis, etc) - depends on types of data you need to save.